# How to draw horizontal line on each bar?

Tags: mql4, mql

I recently started learning the MQL programming language. how to draw a horizontal line on each candle in certain time frames (for example, annual, semi-annual, monthly and weekly) in open, close and min.max prices?

This needs to be done better by downloading the entire history of a particular trading pair. And what is better to do this on an advisor, on an indicator or on a script?